# Multiple apk based on density

Tags: android

I want to upload 3 apk on android market based on density that is ldpi,mdpi and hdpi.

I referred this links
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#MultiApks 
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

How can I use below tag in manifest

```
<compatible-screens></compatible-screens>
```

My application size in large so i want to delete resources based on density and making build according to density

Is this a proper way??

plz help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can not test this in eclipse because in eclipse if you add this tag in it then also application will be installed in any phone..So i am asking you guys who have tested on android market

Comment: regarding screen density testing, you can test it if you modify the screen density of your emulator.

Comment: ` <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    </compatible-screens>`

I have added this code in manifest and i am installing application in my galaxy s..and it is installed successfully..How??..It should not be..but!!!!

Comment: Samsung galaxy s i9000 is having high density... How shold be <compatible-screens></compatible-screens> this tag in manifest so that it will be different for different density.. And also Google play say "don't use both tag <compatible-screens></compatible-screens>  and <supports-screens /> simultaneously in manifest" so im not using <compatible-screens></compatible-screens>

Comment: If you are allowing filters for one size then dont forget to set it  to **false** for all other attributes. Since galaxy s is an hdpi phone, so as per your filters it can install the app, unless (as i said) you set all other attributes to false to narrow down the acceptability

Comment: `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="false"></supports-screens>` this will only allow small screens as candidate to install your app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10471/discussion-between-sunshine-and-waqas)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its fine to have multiple apk files for the same app based on the different sdk/screen/gl features you need to build.

Comment: In My resource folder, I am having resources of mdpi only and if i put android:normalScreens="true" then normal screen is having 2 density HVGA (320x480) and WVGA800 (480x800). and for WVGA, resources will be loaded from mdpi because all folder are empty except mdpi.